# Upload an image to cloudinary with specific public_id to a specific folder (node.js)

Tags: cloudinary

I'm trying to upload an image to a specific folder and also set the public_id.

I read the documentation here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference

My code is:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
   localImagePath,
   {
      public_id: '/my_folder/my_public_id',
      folder: 'my_folder',
      resource_type: 'image',
      transformation: 'profile_image'
   },
   (err, url) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(url);
   }
);
```

But the image is uplaoded to this path: `'my_folder/my_folder/my_public_id'`
instead of `my_folder/my_public_id`.

From the docs:

> The public ID contains the full path of the uploaded asset, including
>   the folder name

I tried everything, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the folder twice - once in the `public_id` and again in the `folder` option.

Given that you are passing both upload options, the resulting `public_id` of the image will be `<folder>/<public_id>`.

You can omit the `folder` parameter completely and you will be getting your expected result (`/my_folder/my_public_id`).